# insert into multiple tables in php within a single form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have created a form and here is the insert command for inserting values into the database. The first query $query1 is executed but the second one is not. So I am getting the "seller INSERT failed"

```
<?php
$book_author = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_author']);;
$book_branch = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_branch']);
$book_edit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_edit']);
$book_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_name']);
$book_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_price']);
$book_pub = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_pub']);
$book_qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_qty']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['s_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$phNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phNo']);
$clg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['college']);

$query1 = "INSERT INTO `book_info`(book_author,book_branch,book_edit,book_name,book_price,book_pub,book_qty) VALUES".
"('$book_author','$book_branch','$book_edit','$book_name','$book_price','$book_pub','$book_qty')";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO `seller_info`(seller_name,seller_email,seller_phno,seller_college) VALUES".
"('$name','$email','$phNo','$clg')";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
if (!$result1)
   echo "Book INSERT failed: $query1";
if (!$result2)
   echo "seller INSERT failed $query2 <br />".
mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";

?>
```

Comment: Only a guess, what is seller_phno? Do you mean seller_phone?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Placeholders also avoid the giant mess of "escape string" calls you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this after the failing query, or in place of `echo "seller INSERT failed $query2 <br />".`

```
echo mysqli_error($con);
```

This will tell you exactly what the error was. (It might be `seller_phno` not being spelled correctly.)

More information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)